# .NET rich clients: how to manage configuration settings in a Dependency Injection architecture

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, configuration, rich-client-platform

I'm developing a solution involving multiple .NET rich clients, a central server and a database containing configuration settings. I want to follow a properly decoupled architecture and *not* treat application settings like global variables. Instead I want to simply use Dependency Injection to pass the retrieved configuration values to constructors upon app startup as the object graph is built.

This seems straight-forward and simple... except when dealing with changes to settings at run-time. I have noticed that modern applications typically do not require a restart in order for changes to take effect. This is not only a nice convenience for the user, but may be downright necessary when it comes to multiple clients and services that depend on these settings.

I cannot understand how these two ideals (settings injected at startup, and seamless run-time setting value updates) can be achieved. In other words, the only way I can imagine all clients using the up-to-date settings is for all settings-dependent classes relying on some kind of IAppConfiguration service that always queries for the latest value upon each request. Not only does this seem to promote a poor architecture (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15346096/1628429)), but it would degrade performance (e.g. if a database query were involved).

Thanks

Comment: A long time ago and a galaxy down in Orlando (2008?) I remember a session where "Greg" had services for configuration in his stocktrader wcf app.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074.aspx  No idea if it is "still in there", but just a breadcrumb if you want to pursue.

Comment: I didn't see any configuration in the current version of Stock Trader RI, but thanks anyways

Comment: He may have deprecated it.  Like I said......it was a long time ago....but he made a big deal about being able to update configuration AT A SINGLE SOURCE for all the WCF clients and servers out there.

Comment: I assumed that when you wrote "wcf" that it was a typo and you meant WPF. I was not aware that Stock Trader RI ever used WCF.

Comment: Nope, I meant WCF.  https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-High-Performance-WCF-NET-Stock-Trader-with-Greg-Leake

Comment: You are right... unfortunately they must have remove the download link as well as any WCF- or config-related guidance. Thanks the help anyways.

Comment: One such approach might be to use a cache (such as the one from System.Runtime.Caching) to store the settings *and* provide a way for the cache settings to be written. Then, whenever a setting is updated in the application, it can write the value to both the cache and data store in one transaction. In DI terms, this would likely mean wrapping both your data read and writing classes into a decorator so these cache writes are transparent to the caller. The result is a setting that changes at runtime and persists across cache reloads.

Comment: Another option: [Application Configuration for .NET](http://www.west-wind.com/westwind.applicationconfiguration/).

Comment: Thanks--I was not aware of System.Runtime.Caching... looks like it could be an elegant solution.

Comment: Look for "CacheAside" pattern from msdn as well.