# Registering factory method doesn't prevent Autofac from calling ctor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, factory-method

I have a service called `ServiceConfiguration` which has a non-default ctor. I'm trying to register it through Autofac with a factory method:

```
builder.Register(c=>LoadConfiguration())
       .As<ServiceConfiguration>();
```

And here is the simple `LoadConfiguration` method:

```
private ServiceConfiguration LoadConfiguration() {
    const string fileName = "app.json";
    var json = File.ReadAllText(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceConfiguration>(json);
    return model;
}
```

I expect Autofac to call the `LoadConfiguration` when I asked to resolve `ServiceConfiguration`. But it seems it's trying to call a `ctor` on `ServiceConfiguration`. E.g. calling this line:

```
var c = container.Resolve<ServiceConfiguration>();
```

causes this error:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An error occurred during
> the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception
> for details. Registration: Activator = ServiceConfiguration
> (ReflectionActivator), Services = [ServiceConfiguration], Lifetime =
> Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared,
> Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope'

and the InnerException is:

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with
> 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
> 'ServiceConfiguration' can be invoked with the available services and
> parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'JobsConfiguration jobs' of constructor 'Void .ctor(JobsConfiguration)'.

Can you find out what I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**
I'm not missing a registration of `JobsConfiguration`. Actually it's not a registrable type and I don't want to register it. I don't want to `ctor` get called at all (the service is getting build from a json file), instead whenever somebody asked for `ServiceConfiguration` I want Autofac to call `LoadConfiguration()` and use it's returned value.

**UPDATE2:**

After a while, it seems extracting an interface from `ServiceConfiguration` - say `IServiceConfiguration` - and registering/resolving the interface works just fine. But I cannot figure out why! I mean this:

```
builder.Register(c=>LoadConfiguration())
       .As<IServiceConfiguration>();

var c = container.Resolve<IServiceConfiguration>();
```

works. But the concrete version not. So why? What's the difference?

Comment: Are you missing a registration of `JobsConfiguration`?

Comment: @Icepickle see the updated question please

Comment: you don't need to call `.As<ServiceConfiguration>()` as your lambda already returns `ServiceConfiguration`. Are you sure, that your `container` is equal `builder.Build()`?

Comment: also, are you sure, that `LoadConfiguration()` method never called? If it is called somehow - are you sure, that it not throwing any exception?

Comment: @vasily.sib I already have tried without calling `.As<ServiceConfiguration>()`. Same result. Yep, `container ` is `builder.Build()`. What a f question! And NO, the `LoadConfiguration` never get called, and NO I test it, it doesn't throwing any exception.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by _"What a f question!"_ (hope it's not an F-word) but could you provide minimal, complete and verifiable example of this, because my sample works as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You should strive separating the loading of configuration files from Object Composition. This means that it's best *not* to load the configuration when `Resolve` is called. Changing this is trivial:

```
ServiceConfiguration configuration = LoadConfiguration();
builder.RegisterInstance(configuration);
```

That said, your given registration should work:

```
builder.Register(c => LoadConfiguration())
    .As<ServiceConfiguration>();
```

Which is identical to:

```
builder.Register(c => LoadConfiguration());
```

With this registration, Autofac will *not* Auto-Wire the `ServiceConfiguration` constructor, but will leave that to the supplied delegate. There might be something going on that your post is not showing.

I used the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), using Autofav 4.8.1, to verify that this works:

```
class ServiceConfiguration
{
    public ServiceConfiguration(int a, double b) => Console.WriteLine("ctor called.");
}

static ServiceConfiguration LoadConfiguration() => new ServiceConfiguration(2, 6);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.Register(_ => LoadConfiguration()).As<ServiceConfiguration>();

    builder.Build().Resolve<ServiceConfiguration>();
}
```

Last note: Make sure that `ServiceConfiguration` is not an application-wide configuration class that is injected into many consumers. To understand what's wrong with application-wide configuration classes, please read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345594/how-to-using-dependency-injection-get-configuration-from-multiple-sources/15346096#15346096).

Comment: Thanks to answer. I tried all possible combination of registration (including your mentioned ones) but none of them work. Seems only extracting interface from service and register/resolve that, can help. And thanks to the last note. Ill read it for sure.

Comment: Don't forget to always include the full stack trace, and please try to be nice to the commenters. They are trying to help you.