# How to check directory in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

Hellow everyone i have problem with test.
I have class

```
  public class RepositoryWorker
    {
        public IRepository Repository { get;}
        private string _path;
        public RepositoryWorker(IRepository repository)
        {

            if (repository is XmlRepository)
            {
                Repository = repository;
                CheckDirectoryForXMl();
            }

            if (repository is JsonRepository)
            {
                Repository = repository;
                CheckDirectoryForJson();
            }
        }

        public void WriteConfig(Config config)
        {
            Repository.WriteConfig(config,_path);
        }

        public Config ReadConfig(string path)
        {
            return Repository.ReadConfig(path, _path);
        }

        private void CheckDirectoryForXMl()
        {

            _path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("XmlConfigPath"));
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(_path);
            if (!directory.Exists)
            {
                directory.Create();
            }
        }

        private void CheckDirectoryForJson()
        {
            _path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("JsonConfigPath"));
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(_path);
            if (!directory.Exists)
            {
                directory.Create();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a variable path that gets a value from the current directory and app.config, but in the tests I get null, because I can't get this path from the config how can I solve this problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key ="XmlConfigPath" value ="XmlConfigs"/>
        <add key ="JsonConfigPath" value ="JsonConfigs"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are combining tow strings 1) Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() 2) ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("XmlConfigPath")  check the two strings (and the combined string) to see if path is valid.  The path could be relative or absolute.  If relative the starting location of the path is the folder where the application executable is located (like debug or release folder).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to, using dependency injection, get configuration from multiple sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345594/how-to-using-dependency-injection-get-configuration-from-multiple-sources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an app.config file in your test project with the same appsettings, or different values for testing.

A better way however would be to create an interface to access your settings and inject it in your code using dependecy injection.

In your unit test you could then create a Mock of your interface and setup the required values.

Sample:

```
public interface ISettings
{
   string GetValue(string name);
}

public class Settings : ISettings
{
   public string GetValue(string name) => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(name);
}

// Use ISettings the same as you use IRepository
_path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), _settings.GetValue("JsonConfigPath"));
```

Depending on your mocking framework you can write the following in your tests.
(This is the syntax for Moq)

```
var settingsMock = new Mock<ISettings>();
settingsMock.Setup(x => x.GetValue(It.IsAny<string>())
   .Returns("Your test value");
```

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but do I need to create an interface in the main project or in the test project?

Comment: In the main project, as you want to program against the interface, since ConfigurationManager is a dependency you can't mock.